# Convert FASTQ ASCII to decimal and hexadecimal in R

Tags: r, ascii, fastq

I have a FASTQ quality score which is presented as a series of ASCII characters. In this case (*likely*) ASCII character 64 to 126 represent the a score of 0 to 62 (*presuming it is Illumina*). This gives rise to underlying sequence :

> feffefdfbefdfffcfdeTddaYddffbfcI``S_KKX_]]MR[D_TY[VTVXQ]`Q_BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

How do I extract which is the number of the ASCII characters?

Thank you
San

EDIT:
This sequence denotes the quality of a biological sequence that is made up of bases (from base pairs in nucleic acids, meaning a character (ATGC)). A base quality is the phred-scaled base error probability which equals -10 log10 Pr{base is wrong}.

Comment: What do you mean by an ASCII score?

Comment: More info required - what are all those letters? Did you really think this makes sense to anyone? Try again.

Comment: Please wait while I reboot my crystal ball.

Comment: Looks like [FASTQ format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format) to me. If yes then try to search over [BioConductor](http://www.bioconductor.org/).

Comment: I don't know about you guys but all I see are blondes and brunettes!

Comment: @Marek : good catch. Is there a function to convert Illumina quality scores?

Comment: Edited the question to make a bit more clear what the question is.

Comment: Actually, this question comes up in handling sequencing data, so the question was useful.  I found an answer here:  http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/ht-seq#TOC-Handling-of-Sequence-and-Quality-Da

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, as Marek said : you might find a function to convert Illumina quality scores in Bioconductor. You can ask at [biostar.stackexchange.com](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/).

Using base functions, you can use `charToRaw()`:

```
> x <- "feeffdbefc`\\KKX]_BBBB"
> charToRaw(x)
 [1] 66 65 65 66 66 64 62 65 66 63 60 5c 4b 4b 58 5d 5f 42 42 42 42
> as.numeric(charToRaw(x))
 [1] 102 101 101 102 102 100  98 101 102  99  96  92  75  75  88  93  95  66  66  66  66
> as.character(charToRaw(x))
 [1] "66" "65" "65" "66" "66" "64" "62" "65" "66" "63" "60" "5c" "4b" "4b" "58" "5d" "5f" "42" "42" "42" "42"
```

Mind you, you'll have to escape the backslash, or you'll get into trouble. That depends on how you read in your data and so forth.

Comment: Around the topic: http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/processing-fastq-files-in-r-bioconductor-without-reading-entire-files-into-memory

Comment: How to replace the backslash with 2 backslashes? I tried sub('\\', '/', str) but getting an error.